Необходим алгоритм рассадки игроков за 9ти местным столом

задача такова
24 игровых дня. Каждый день играют все игроки, 3 стола по 9 человек.
Всего 72 стола (вместительность каждого стола 9 человек). Мне необходимо, что бы каждый игрок сыграл с другими игроками равное количество раз.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //1. Опишите точнее текущий алгоритм, который вы используете 2. Уточните, что вы подразумеваете под "максимально ровным пересечением" и каким образом измеряете разбег 3. Приведите примеры результатов работы ваших текущих подходов (круговой системы, деления на подгруппы), чтобы лучше понять проблему

Люблю алгоритмы и математику, но что вы спрашиваете не понимаю совсем. Почему столов может быть не три? Это круговой турнир? Сколько кругов? Как считаются "пересечения"? Что значит "максимально ровное пересечение"? Что такое "погрешность пересечения"? Что такое "круговая система"? Что такое "разбег"?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, я тоже нифига не понял, но может быть, надо иногда столы перемешивать и в итоге получить примерно равное время нахождения за одним столом для каждой пары участников (хотя, тогда столов всё равно 3). Другой вариант, что каждый играет за произвольным числом столов, куда его посадили.

@Qwertiy, я согласен с вами. Да только уж очень хочется работать с хорошо поставленной задачей, не гадать.

Доброе утро Вам.
Qwertiy, Вы правы.
Изначально задача такова
есть 27 участник
есть 72 стола (вместительность каждого стола 9 человек)
мне нужно, что бы каждый игрок сыграл с другими равное количество раз.
игрок 1 с 2-27 условно 5 раз и так же 2 с 1/3-27 5раз

мне нужно, что бы каждый игрок сыграл с другими равное количество раз.
игрок 1 с 2-27 условно 5 раз и так же 2 с 1/3-27 5раз и так далее
но, так как есть ограничение по количеству столов, то и появляется погрешность/разбег, условно кто то с кем то 6 раз, а кто то 8 - это нормально. но у меня получается кто то 6, а кто то 12.
пробовала делать подгруппы деля их на три и переставляла их между собой, а после добивала разницу между самими группами.

Игрок может сидеть за несколькими столами одновременно? Число игроков за столом произвольное (но не больше 9) или фиксированное? Считается что игрок сыграл со всеми партнерами по столу? Можно ли, чтобы разные игроки седели за разным числом столов? ...

1 день три стола, всего игровых дня 24, но 24 +-. За каждым столом фиксированно по 9 человек. то есть грубо говоря у меня получается три подгруппы и мне их нужно так рассаживать что бы в конечном итоге каждый друг с другом сыграли по примерно равное количество раз (это я и называю пересечениями)

Есть точное решение (когда каждая пара игроков играет ровно 8 партий), с 26-ю игровыми днями. Что важнее соблюсти число дней или минимизировать различие между минимальнмым-максимольным число партия для разных пар?

Пара? у меня же игроков обязательно 9 за столом. мне важно минимизировать различие для каждого игрока с другими 26 игроками. [(группа + номер)MOD n, номер] вот что то типа такого, ноя не смогла ее применить.

Но всего пар игроков 27*(27-1)/2 == 351. Если 9 разных игроков встретились за одним столов, то 9*(9-1)/2=36 пар игроков, играли партию за этим столов. Попробуйте все-таки поправить вопрос так, чтобы оно содержал полное описание задачи (ответы которые вы дали в комментариях). Или вставьте полный текст задачи, которая вам задана, дословно. Возможно, при пересказе потеряна какая-то важная информация.

у меня турнир на 27 участников.
Проходит турнир за столами с посадкой 9 человек.
Дней ориентировочно 24, но дни можно подвинуть.
Каждый день играют все участники, соответственно это три стола по 9 человек
Не могу найти формулу для рассадки игроков таким образом, что бы каждый игрок сыграл равное количество раз с другими игроками .

https://www.online-python.com/lx4czIHDKf - оно? И все-таки поправьте текст вопроса, (не надо писать комментарии).

спасибо тебе, добрый человек. Да, это то что нужно. не знаю как тут отблагодарить или повысить тебе рейтинг, действительно помог, СПАСИБО.

Мария, не знаю как тут отблагодарить или повысить рейтинг ===> исправьте свой вопрос так, чтоб его открыли -> проверят, чтоб открыть (если ок)-> вопрос откроют -> добрый человек оформит решение ответом -> вы примете его ответ как верный (галочка под ответом зеленая) -> и проголосуете "за" его ответ ...(если не ок и не открыли вопрос) -> исправьте так, чтоб было ок, ...// пока вопрос закрыт - на него невозможно ответить

@Chorkov, у вас действительно очень изящное решение! Использование индексов Миллера и комбинаторики позволяет создать равномерное расписание, что впечатляет. Было бы замечательно, если бы вы опубликовали это как ответ, чтобы оно не затерялось в комментариях и могло быть полезно другим в будущем
